# Convert Hashmap to JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a `HashMap<String, String>`, where the value strings can be either a long or double. For example, `123.000` can be stored as `123` (stored as long), and `123.45` as `123.45` (double).

Take these two hashmap values:

> ("one", "123");  ("two", "123.45")

When I convert the above map into a JSON string, the JSON values should not have double quotes, like

> Expected: {"one": 123, "two": 123.45 }
>
> Actual: {"one": "123", "two": "123.45" }

This is my code below:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(map)
```

I prefer a solution using GSON, but using another library or libraries is also welcome.

Comment: Actually, yes [they should](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627)

Comment: Transform your current map into a `Map<String,Double>`, or `Map<String, Number>` and store appropriate values.

Comment: Why down voting if you dont like the question? There is nothing wrong in asking the above question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis using Map<String, Double> or Map<String, Number> converts the values to { "one": 123.0, "two": 123.45 } where there is extra zero(s) which I don't want in the final json

Comment: Works fine for me with a `Map<String, Number>`. I use `map.put("one", 125);` and it prints `{"one":125}`.

Comment: To convert 123.000000 to 123 (instead of 123.000), and 123.456789 to 123.456, I read values from Map<String, Double>, trim unwanted zeros, and roundoff  and then store the result in Map<String, String>. But If I do like you say, then I cannot get rid of those unwanted zeros/roundoff.

Answer (score 8):

For Gson you'll get the following conversions:

```
Map<String, Double> -> {"one": 123, "two":123.45}
Map<String, Number> -> {"one": 123, "two":123.45}
Map<String, String> -> {"one": "123", "two": "123.45"}
```

Basically, there's no way to get Gson to automatically convert your strings to numeric values. If you want them to show up as numeric (i.e. without quotes) you need to store the appropriate datatype in the map, `Double` or `Number`.

Also, Json only has a limited number of primitive types, it stores string or numeric. A numeric value does not distinguish between `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, etc. so I'm not sure why you are trying to distinguish them. Once it's stored as Json it's all considered as the same numeric type.

Comment: Yes, but I want to change its default behavior as mentioned in the question

Comment: @user3366706 Why not just use/convert-to a Map<String, Double>. There's no point trying to distinguish between Double and Integer because once it's in Json all you have is a single numeric type.

Comment: @user3366706 I'm pretty sure I understand your question.  The answer is that that's not how Gson works. It won't try to convert your strings into numeric values when going from `Map<String,String>` to json. You need to start with `Map<String, Double>` or `Map<String, Number>`.

Comment: using Map<String, Double> or Map<String, Number> converts the values to  { "one": 123.0, "two": 123.45 } where there is extra zero(s) which I don't want in the final json

Comment: @user3366706 It doesn't matter either way because json doesn't distinguish between integer and double, it's just a numeric datatype -- a json value of 123 is the same as 123.0. What matters is datatype in your map when you try to convert the json back to Java: Map<String, Double> will assume everything is double (even if there is no decimal), and Map<String, Integer> will assume everything is int (even if it has a decimal). If you really want to keep your exact formatting you will have to store it as a string, "123".

Comment: Yes, so there is no actual solution for the problem. Bare with unwanted zeros if loaded as double, or chop decimal values if loaded as int, or keep it as string itself. right?

Comment: @user3366706 Yes, but the real answer is that it doesn't make a difference whether the 0's are there or not once it is in json, so you shouldn't be trying to control that. And if you need the formatting exactly the same then you had your solution from the start -- use String type.

Answer (score 0):

This is very  late to answer this but it will help someone who stumble upon this issue like me.

Use following link to build your custom Gson serialization which will parse the numeric string to appropriate number type. (simple if-else or switch based on decimal point).

[Gson Custom Serialization and Deserialization](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)